# How to overcome UI slowdown using ngFor with big arrays in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, performance

I have an array with 5 items. Each item represents a year with 365 days. In the template I have to render all those days as a colored `div` 10x10 pixels year by year (the result is supposed to be a grid of styled `div`s, so pagination won't work for this case).

When the page is rendered and I scroll down, UI works slowly with freezes.

I tried enabling `OnPush` change strategy on the component, but that didn't help.